# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugShaders' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime-error, flutter-dependencies

When I try to run my code I get this error (no errors or warnings in flutter doctor):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any corrupted images/gifs/videos etc. If you have anything that requires a special encoder to run, this error probably will show up.

But if everything is okay, just add this line in your build.gradle file.

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

This will probably solve your problems.